# Creating Relationships with Same Label but Different Properties

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

My goal is to create dynamic relationships with timestamp stored as property of the relationship. So, 2 nodes may have many relationships with the same label but different property values.

I can achieve that using Cypher by the following:

```
CREATE 
(s1:Node {name:'s1'}), 
(s2:Node{name:'s2'}), 
(s1)-[r1:CONNECTS_TO{from:456}]->(s2), 
(s1)-[r2:CONNECTS_TO{from:1234}]->(s2)
```

However, I cannot find the same way to do that using Py2neo.
I tried this:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

graph = Graph(password='neo4jneo4j')

s1 = Node('Node', name='s1')
s2 = Node('Node', name='s2')

aw = Relationship(s1, 'CONNECTS_TO', s2, from=456)
graph.create(aw)

aw2 = Relationship(s1, 'CONNECTS_TO', s2, from=1234)
graph.create(aw2)
```

The code above doesn't create two relationships. Instead, the latter one updates the former one.

How can I do it using Py2neo?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste a code snippet that would actually run. The variables `arif` and `wicaksana` are not defined.

Comment: @NicoleWhite sorry for that, just updated the snippet with the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the py2neo `Node` and `Relationship` objects. You'll have to use Cypher to create multiple similar relationships like this.

Comment: Initially, I thought that I wouldn't use low-level query using Cypher. But apparently in my case I have to use it. Thanks Nigel for the clarification!